# How to redirect the user on FB notification click directly to the App

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I've implemented **share with friends** functionality pop-up box with a friend list using Graph API. When a user selects their friends and click done, the notification goes to their friends FB notification tray in our Android and iOS app. When a user clicks on that notification instead of opening up the app directly it's opening the app page in Google play (android) and App store (iOS).

Yes I'm aware of the fact that FB says their notification is smart enough to know whether user who's clicking on the notification in their phone, already have the app installed or not and accordingly they will redirect the user.

The below URL if you check and go to **Accept Experience**, that's the same way our app is working but just not going to App.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1

Our app is approved by Facebook already, so we're live.

Please check below image to check what information I've provided to Facebook.

[image]

Comment: From what you are describing in the question I don't understand what it is that you need help with. Please clarify what the problem is.